# How to know the output of some codes in Magento files?

Tags: eclipse, magento, netbeans

Let’s say I want to know the output of $_productCollection in list.phtml. Surely, I can simply use either var_dump($_productCollection) or print_r($_productCollection) and explicitly load the list.phtml then access it from the browser. However, this is not what I need.

In order to trace the behaviors of Magento codes, I need to know right on the spot the output of every codes (without having to access it through browser to see the output). Is it possible to do that?

I tried both eclipse and netbeans but I have no idea how to see the output of any codes inside any files. Can someone guide me how to achieve this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use xdebug but if you can't get xdebug to work and just want something like var_dump without stopping the flow you can also add Mage::log($somevar) wherever you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a debugger.  [XDebug](http://xdebug.org).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. XDebug does work well for non-MVC sites where all files can be accessed independently. But for MVC site like Magento, I got forbidden error every time I want to debug a file either as a script or a web page. I might have done something wrong, but I really don't know how to make that works. Again thank you any suggestion.

Comment: You can debug as a browser session. Once your browser is open with an active xdebug session you just browse your site or post a form etc until your breakpoints are hit.

Comment: Not sure what I've done wrong, but every time I click Debug, it just keeps rolling and rolling forever (127.0.0.1/magento/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug). However, for individual file like single test file, it does work.